# How can I remove IP addresses from log files after some time

Tags: nginx, web-server, logging, apache2, privacy

I have an apache/nginx/whatever web server which logs client IP addresses to the access logs. Now these log files are rotated via `logrotate`.

I want to keep the IP addresses for some days, then after 7 days, I want to remove the IPs from the log files for privacy reasons (mostly dictated by German law).

Using `mod_removeip` or something like that doesn't work because I need to filter some requests based on their IP addresses.

Is there any 'standard' way to do it? Maybe even with `logrotate`?

**EDIT**

I just found [this script](http://www.zendas.de/technik/sicherheit/apache/index.html) but it depends on the ability to pipe all logging through the script in real-time. I'm not really sure about the performance implication of this approach.

Also, this only works for the 'front-end' server logs, not the application server logs.

Answer (score 2):

PCRE! (Perl-Compatible Regular Expression)

```
s/\b(1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.(1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.(1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.(1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\b/REMOVED IP/g
```

Use that as a filter in a perl script or any other suitable language (quite a few use PCRE or some other close-enough regex language that will work) to rewrite your log files at 7 days.

```
$ cat > file_with_ip
some text from 192.168.1.1
^D
$ perl -p -i -e 's/\b(1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.(1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.(1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.(1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\b/REMOVED IP/g' file_with_ip
$ cat file_with_ip
some text from REMOVED IP
```

Answer (score 1):

On `Ubuntu > 12.04` / `apache 2.4`, with default config you could use something like this:

```
for file in `find /var/log/apache2 -type f -name ".*gz"  ! -name "*.ano.*" -mtime +7`
do
    datestamp=`date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%s"`
    # echo Process $file
    zcat $file |sed -E "s/([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/\1.0.0/"|gzip > ${file%.*}.ano.${datestamp}.gz 
    # rm -f $file # Only call this if you are sure that the command before succeeds, otherwise you will lose data.
done
```

This creates a copy of all `*.gz` files older then 7 days and replaces the last two bytes of all `IPs` `0.0` in the copied version with `ano` suffix added.

If you don't use compression or different compression like `bz2` you have to change the commands accordingly, e.g. `zcat` -> `bzcat`.

Finally you can call this routine via `cron` once per day/week.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think logrotate will do it; you may need to look at creating a script that will decompress the files, process them through awk or sed to strip the IP's out, then recompress them. Just can't do it on "active" log files.

Comment: I believe logrotate has pre/post hooks that you could use to launch the script you mention, then the OP wouldn't need to manage a separate process.

Comment: Maybe you can use logroate's "postrotate" for this.

Comment: i even thought of creating a "compress" script which filters and then pipes to gzip. this would essentially save the step of decompressing the logs but would 'kill' the time window of 7 days i want